# Child Model List is Empty after DB Add in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

So I am trying out Entity Framework Core, and am having trouble with my first pair of relational Models. I'm trying to use conventions to form the relationship, as follows:

The principal entity, with conventional principal key (Id) and collection navigation property (the list of Locations):

```
public class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int LocationCount { get; set; } = 1;
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; } = new List<Location>();
}
```

The dependent entity, with conventional foreign key (SiteId) and reference navigation property (Site):

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    public int AreaCount { get; set; } = 1;
    public Location(Site site) { SiteId = site.Id; }
}
```

And since I want every Site to already have at least one location, I put this in the Create action of the SiteController, in an attempt to create the dependents along with the principal:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Site site)
{
    _context.Sites.Add(site);
    for (int i = 0; i < site.LocationCount; i++)
        _context.Locations.Add(new Location(site));
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { Name = site.Name });
}
```

However, on the Details view, when I try to display the Locations that were created, the list is always empty:

```
<h2>@Model.Locations.Count Locations</h2>    
@foreach (Location l in Model.Locations)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">@l.Id</div>
    </div>
}
```

Just results in:

```
0 Locations
```

Thank you in advance for any help explaining what I've missed!

**Edit:** By request, here is the body of the Details action in the Site Controller, which gets the Model data for the Details View:

```
public IActionResult Details(string name)
{
    var model = _context.Sites.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == name);
    if (model == null) model = new Site();
    return View(model);
}
```

Also, per one suggestion, I have fixed the problem of setting the Location.SiteId before Site.Id has a value, since the Id isn't automatically generated on the Site until after SaveChanges() is called. Unfortunately, the result (empty Locations list) is still the same:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Site site)
{
    int nextsiteid = _context.Sites.Count() + 1;
    _context.Sites.Add(site);
    for (int i = 0; i < site.LocationCount; i++)
        _context.Locations.Add(new Location(siteid));
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { Name = site.Name });
}
```

And changed the Location constructor to use the Id instead of the instance:

```
public Location(int siteid) { SiteId = siteid; }
```

Thanks in advance for any further suggestions!

Comment: How are you getting data from view ?

Comment: @AsifRaza I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean how am I getting the Site data from the Site View? Just the usual way, declare the model, fill out the form, and submit it through HttpPost to that Create method I showed above. The children are not created through the Create View, though. I just want to create one or more "default" instances of the Location dependents when the Site is created. So the Location doesn't have a View.

Comment: Ok , you are just Passing Parent value where as you are adding child data i'm right-

Comment: That was the intention, yes. (1) Create parent by way of "_context.Sites.Add(site);" and then (2) Create some default children for that parent by way of "for (int i = 0; i < site.LocationCount; i++) _context.Locations.Add(new Location(site));" Inside the Child constructor I try to make the relationship by way of "public Location(Site site) { SiteId = site.Id; }"

Comment: I have update my anwser i hope this will help

Comment: Can we see how you get the data for the Details view?

Comment: @IvanStoev Sure! I added to my post above the body of the Details action on the Site Controller. I hope that's what you meant!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant :) Looks like your collection is simply not populated because there is no lazy loading in EF Core yet. You might consider reading the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the documentation. Shortly, you need `Include`, e.g. `var model = _context.Sites.Include(s => s.Locations).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == name);`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much. That was exactly the problem. I hadn't even considered that EF Core might not support lazy loading, and completely missed this sentence my first time through that document: "Lazy loading is not yet possible with EF Core." I added eager loading and now the list populates fine! Thank you very much! If you'd like credit for the answer, feel free to post it and I'll mark it!

Comment: You are welcome mate, glad it helped :) No credits needed, happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just transcribing the answer I was given, which was provided in the comments of the original post, so that it can easily be found by anyone reading the post.

The issue was, quite simply, that EF Core does not yet support lazy loading. So when the Site entity is populated, it doesn't lazily load the list of dependent locations into the collection navigation property.

The fix is to use eager loading, by way of:

```
var model = _context.Sites.Include(s => s.Locations).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == name);
```

When loading the Model data of the Site to provide to the View.

Thanks for the solution, Ivan!

Answer (score 0):

if the Lazy Loading is true. No need to loop over or navigate its child. its will save your parent and as well its child. make sure are you getting parents and its child

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Site site)
{  // debug here are you getting parent & its child ?
_context.Sites.Add(site);
   // for (int i = 0; i < site.LocationCount; i++)  // No need of it
   // _context.Locations.Add(new Location(site));   // No need of it
_context.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { Name = site.Name });
}
```

Updated:
if these two tables are linked with each other & you are manually trying to add location table . Let me give you a simple , hope this will help you

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Site site)
{  // debug here are you getting parent & its child ?
_context.Sites.Add(site);
   // get the last added site id

   int? maxId=
  _context.Sites.orderbyDecending(x=>x.SiteId).FirstorDefault(x=>x.SiteId);// may be in this line typing mistake , you change it according to linq
    foreach(var i in site.Location) 
    {
      // in this loop traverse the child array and override the foreign key id with last added id
       i.SiteId =maxId;
      _context.Locations.Add(i);
    }

_context.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { Name = site.Name });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I remember reading that lazy loading was true by default, so I figured I didn't need to add the dependents to the principal manually. But I'm not sure how your solution actually adds a new Location row to the Locations table in the database. Would that have to happen somewhere in the Site model? Where does the _context.Locations.Add(LocationInstance) go?

Comment: Where does the _context.Locations.Add(LocationInstance) go? Well it will nothing do , because if you linked between two then you need add primary of site to location table , i hope you understand -

Comment: Oooh, I see. So the problem is that the Site ID value hasn't been set yet, probably because that happens during SaveChanges()? So when I pass the Site into the Location constructor and set the Site ID, it isn't getting the value? That makes sense! I will test this out! Thanks for expanding your explanation!

Comment: I attempted to set the SiteId of the Location by predicted Id value instead of by Site instance, as you demonstrated, but I still get the same result. I don't think my implementation is very different from yours, but I could have missed something. It is added to my post, above.

Comment: How can you predicted Id ? Id is not auto generated ? You can get by max id from entity

Comment: Yes, I assumed that the goal was to predict the next Site Id so that it could be passed to the Location constructor. I thought you were illustrating that because the Id for the Site isn't auto-generated until AFTER SaveChanges is called (when the row is actually inserted into the table). Since the Location needs to be created before that, predicting the next Site Id is necessary. As far as how to predict the next Site Id, what you provided does the trick, but I thought it would be equally effective to just count the number of rows already in the DbSet, since it is an auto-incremented int key.